# Replace / Ignore JavaScript in a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I wrote a small RSS reader with JQuery. At first theres a screen with the titles of the articles, when clicked on a title I load the content of that article. The problem is, it contains some google ads script, which will replace the content of the article and fill the whole screen with an advertisement.

The following script is what I am tying to replace or ignore:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-8356817984200457";
/* ijsselmondenieuws.nl */
google_ad_slot = "9061178822";
google_ad_width = 468;
google_ad_height = 60;
//-->
</script><br />
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

So I wrote a method which is supposed to remove the script by a simple replace:

```
 var replaceScript='<script type="text/javascript"><!--\n' +
'google_ad_client = "ca-pub-8356817984200457";\n' +
'/* ijsselmondenieuws.nl */\n' +
'google_ad_slot = "9061178822";\n' +
'google_ad_width = 468;\n' +
'google_ad_height = 60;\n' +
'//-->\n' +
'</script>\n' +
'<script type="text/javascript"\n' +
'src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">\n' +
'</script>';



function removeADS(ads) {
    removeAD = ads.replace(replaceScript, " ");
}
```

But this doesn't work, I think it's not flexible either (if it would work). When something changes in the script, the application will get stuck at the advertisement again. Is there some way to completely ignore this script while fetching the content from an RSS feed or a more flexible replacement script?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: use a dom parser! don't parse xml with regex full stop

Comment: @gion_13: does this work with a rendered dom (or parts like this script which is already executed?). the string part he wants to replace must be present to be replaced. if its present, the javascript is already or will be executed. i dont see a way how to replace this on the client side. if there is some way i would appreciate if you add this solution as a comment

Comment: I get the content by the following line: `content:$.trim($(v).find("content").text())`, the content also contains the script. Isn't there another way to ignore/replace the script without using a dom parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very wise to parse xml/html with regex.
Use a dom parser (jquery is a beautiful one ...hint hint):

```
var rssContentString = '<rss version='2.0'>...',
    xmlDoc = $.parseXml(rssContentString),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    helper = $('<div />'),
    result;


result = helper
    .append(
        $xml
            .find('script')
                .remove()
                .end()
    )
    .text();
```

**UPDATE**
Based on the new comments, since you get your rss content like this :

```
content:$.trim($(v).find("content").text())
```

you can modify this expression to the following :

```
content:$.trim($(v).find("content").find('script').remove().end().text())
```

Comment: I would like to accept your answer but I still didn't get it to work. I tried your updated answer, but somehow it's still showing the advertisement. I am not very sure how to use the first part of your answer, my JS knowledge is kind of basic. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't know exactly why it isn't working. Give an example of your work on jsfiddle or provide the rss content.

Comment: This is the rss content I am fetching: `http://www.ijsselmondenieuws.nl/feed/` I am getting the content which are between the `<content:encoded>` tags. I added a div with the id reclame, to make it easier to filter out with this regex `/<div id="reclame">.*<\/div>/gi` but somehow it is still switching to another page.